# error 2003 : can't connect on '192.168.1.180' (10061)?

Tags: mysql, windows, database-connection, ping

I am trying to log into server using -

```
mysql -u abc -p abc -h 192.168.1.180
```

But getting error -

```
error 2003 : can't connect on '192.168.1.180' (10061)
```

Please help me out how to connect.

I am using window 7 and trying to connect win xp.
i am able to ping win 7 but win 7 not able to ping me(just for information).

Comment: 10061 is 'network connection refused'.  Check if mysql is actually listening with netstat -an | find '3306' on the host with mysql.

Comment: can you elaborate how to use netstat? I am new so bit description will be appreciable. thank you

Comment: @DarenSchwenke i checked using above command, there is a record with 0.0.0.0:3306 in that list. do i have to check something else

Answer (score 1):

10061 is 'network connection refused'.

Check if mysql is actually listening with:

```
netstat -an | find '3306'
```

That line, run on the host which has mysql running on it, will tell you if mysql has an open network port.  If mysql is actually externally accessible, it should return one line something like this(pardon me, I run linux so from memory..):

```
TCP  0.0.0.0:3306  0.0.0.0:0  LISTENING
```

Translation..
mysql is listening on all adapters: 0.0.0.0

listening on port 3306  :3306

3306 is the default port.

I believe my.cnf has to have bind-address un-commented to enable network connections though.

Edit: so if it is listening, try getting to it from the other box without involving mysql yet:

```
telnet <mysqlboxip> 3306
```

if that fails, you have a firewall issue.

Edit: Barring a firewall issue, next guess is you have mis-configured one of your network adapters.  Make sure the netmask is the same on both machines, and (without explaining networking) you don't change anything but the last number when changing the address..  For your average home network, netmask should most likely be 255.255.255.0, and ip address should be in the 192.168.(1 or 15).(2-254)

If in doubt, turn dhcp back on, and look at what your router gives you for an address/netmask with:

```
ipconfig -a
```

Most home routers reserve upper addresses for dhcp assigned, so pick a low one.  Stay outside the range used by the router for dhcp basically.

To see where the machine thinks it should sending the traffic:

```
tracert <mysqlboxip>
```

An incorrect netmask or a faulty route on either box could cause the traffic destined for the other box to go out the public internet way or off into nothingness.

Comment: I have checked netstat command its showing the same. In my machine win 7 my.ini I have deleted bind-address and firewall is also off.
I also want to tell you that i am able to ping that machine (win xp) but that machine is not able to ping my win 7. Is there any problem from that side?

Answer (score 0):

There shoudn't be space between `-p` and `abc`  as `abc` is password

```
mysql -u abc -pabc -h 192.168.1.180
```

Also Check `bind-address` in `my.cnf` it should be commented and also check your firewall settings.

Comment: i have tried the same, still getting the same error.

Comment: Check `bind-address` in my.cnf it should be commented and also check your firewall settings.

Comment: i have my.ini, and there was no bind-address row in this file but i added after reading somewhere. Should i delete that once again?

Comment: Yes comment that line and restart mysql or set that to 0.

Answer (score 0):

First you confirm this address is being ping by doing this

ping 192.168.1.180